# Boosting field prefix match in Elasticsearch

Tags: lucene, elasticsearch

Is there a way to boost the scores of prefix **field** matches over term matches later in the field?  Most of the Elasticsearch/Lucene documentation seems to focus on terms rather than fields.

For example, when searching for `femal*`, I'd like to have `Female` rank higher than `Microscopic examination of specimen from female`.  Is there a way to do this on the query side or would I need to do something like create a separate field consisting of the the first word?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To do this, you could e.g. use a [bool](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html)-query with a `should` to weigh in a [span_first](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-span-first-query.html)-query which in turn has a [span_multi](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-span-multi-term-query.html)

Here is a runnable example you can play with: https://www.found.no/play/gist/8107157

```
#!/bin/bash

export ELASTICSEARCH_ENDPOINT="http://localhost:9200"

# Index documents
curl -XPOST "$ELASTICSEARCH_ENDPOINT/_bulk?refresh=true" -d '
{"index":{"_index":"play","_type":"type"}}
{"title":"Female"}
{"index":{"_index":"play","_type":"type"}}
{"title":"Female specimen"}
{"index":{"_index":"play","_type":"type"}}
{"title":"Microscopic examination of specimen from female"}
'

# Do searches

# This will match all documents.
curl -XPOST "$ELASTICSEARCH_ENDPOINT/_search?pretty" -d '
{
    "query": {
        "prefix": {
            "title": {
                "prefix": "femal"
            }
        }
    }
}
'

# This matches only the two first documents.
curl -XPOST "$ELASTICSEARCH_ENDPOINT/_search?pretty" -d '
{
    "query": {
        "span_first": {
            "end": 1,
            "match": {
                "span_multi": {
                    "match": {
                        "prefix": {
                            "title": {
                                "prefix": "femal"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
'

# This matches all, but prefers the one's with a prefix match.
# It's sufficient that either of these match, but prefer that both matches.
curl -XPOST "$ELASTICSEARCH_ENDPOINT/_search?pretty" -d '
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
                {
                    "span_first": {
                        "end": 1,
                        "match": {
                            "span_multi": {
                                "match": {
                                    "prefix": {
                                        "title": {
                                            "prefix": "femal"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match": {
                        "title": {
                            "query": "femal"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
'
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the fully worked example!  I hadn't spotted `span_first`. The results are now much more in line with what the users are expecting.  There's obviously a lot to learn in the Query DSL...

Comment: Why include the span_first in the second example? Why not just use span_multi? Does the span_first improve the scoring algorithm? From the "Play" site, it appears that you would get all three examples, and slightly different scoring, but you would still fulfill the requirements of the question